# library mention swift when typing @ like twitter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I have 'facebook like' project to learn ios mobile development, the feature i want to create right now is mention another user in comment UITextView.
i already tried library SZMentionswift, but i found it very difficult to implement because the example is very confusing to me.
is there any library or example to make listener when user typing '@' then show the list of user like twitter?

thanks

> link to SZMentionsswift https://github.com/szweier/SZMentionsSwift

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help you integrating the library, ref: **Example code** kindly follow the steps

1. Conform to  `UITextViewDelegate`

   private var myInputAccessoryView: UIView?

   ```
   init() {
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
       myInputAccessoryView = SZExampleAccessoryView(delegate: self)
   }
   ```

   add following code and override inputAccessoryView property of UITextField

   override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
           return myInputAccessoryView!
       }
2. Copy `SZExampleAccessoryView.swift` and `SZExampleMentionsTableViewDataManager` file to your code
3. Pass your array to be searched while looking for names to be mentioned in @mention to `names` in `SZExampleMentionsTableViewDataManager.swift`.

this will let you run @ mention same as it is done in example.

Comment: thanks @Deepak its work, but the textview position is always at (x,y) = (0,0).

i already change the init funtion in SZExampleAccessoryView from
super.init(frame: .zero)
to 
super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 0, height: 0))

can you help me with this tricky things
because i want to place button right after the textview